# HSSFWorkbook object is not retaining the sheets added to it through different methods

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
`   class A {
    private HSSFWorkbook workbook;

    public A() {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    }

    public void method1() {
        workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
        System.out.println(" No of sheets: " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets());
        method2();
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println(" No of sheets: " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets());
    }
}
```

In the above code i m creating workbook object in constructor... and creating a "Sheet1" in method1 and its printing No of sheets: 1 in method1 but in method2 the No of sheets: 0...
Why the same workbook object behaves differently in different methods.. Pls some one help me...

Comment: Can you edit your code and add the main Method, where you create an `Instance` of `Class A` and how you call your methods. If i try your code, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I created some times ago also a `Class MyWorkbook` where i was able to add new `Sheet`s , i shorten the following code to show only the two Methods which add the first and all the other `Sheet`s

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class MyWorkbook {

    private final HSSFWorkbook workbook;

    public MyWorkbook() {
        this.workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    }

    public void createNewSheet() {
        workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
        printNumberOfSheets(workbook);
        // here i add the second sheet
        createAnotherSheet();
    }

    public void createAnotherSheet() {
        workbook.createSheet();
        printNumberOfSheets(workbook);
    }

    private void printNumberOfSheets(final HSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        System.out.println("This workbook contains of " + (workbook.getNumberOfSheets() > 1 ? + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets" : workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheet"));
    } 

    public HSSFWorkbook getWorkbook() {
        return workbook;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyWorkbook mw = new MyWorkbook();
        mw.createNewSheet();

        // workbook contains only 1 sheet
        mw.printNumberOfSheets(mw.getWorkbook());

        // here i add the 3rd sheet
        mw.createAnotherSheet();

        // now our workbook contains of 3 sheets
        mw.printNumberOfSheets(mw.getWorkbook());
    }
}
```

Patrick